# Unable to add to blank list

Tags: python

I am working on a program that can be used to add a given value say a car dealership with the cars it owns:

for example

```
car_storage = []

def add_cars(dealership, car):
        for items in car_storage:
            for values in items:
                if dealership in items:

                   #Adds car whether it exists or not in list
                   items.append(car)
                   return
                    
                #If the dealership does not exist it is created and added to the list
                else:

                    items.append([dealership, car])
                    return

add_cars("Manchester", "Mini")
add_cars("London", "Toyota")
add_cars("London", "BMW")
add_cars("London", "BMW")

#Desired output
[["Nottingham", "Audi"],["Manchester","Mini"],["London", "Lorry", "BMW", "BMW"]]
```

However, my code never adds to the list, where am I going wrong?

Comment: `for items in car_storage:` well.. how many times do you expect that to iterate when you first call `add_cars("Manchester", "Mini")`? It's empty. So nothing in the for-loop body executes, and your function terminates

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. Debugging is an important skill for a programmer to develop -- nobody writes flawless code on their first pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code as @juanpa.arrivillaga said is that the before you add the first item the list car_dealership is empty so nothing in your function executes.

Your approach however is almost correct, Python supports else keyword with for loops. What it means is, if the for loop ran without breaking (no break statements) the else statement is called. For example

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    if i==2:
        break
else: # Not executed as there is a break
      # if we remove the break the else will run
    print("No Break")
```

Now similarly in your code. you can use the same concept.

```
def add_cars(dealership, car):
        for items in car_storage:
            for values in items:
                if dealership in items:

                   #Adds car whether it exists or not in list
                   items.append(car)
                   return
                    
        #If the dealership does not exist it is created and added to the list
        else:
            car_storage.append([dealership, car])
```

Which is very similar to your original code except the indentation level on the `else` part.

Now in this case since you're returning and not breaking you can even get away with removing the else entirely since the function will never reach there

```
def add_cars(dealership, car):
        for items in car_storage:
            for values in items:
                if dealership in items:

                   #Adds car whether it exists or not in list
                   items.append(car)
                   return
                    
        #If the dealership does not exist it is created and added to the list
        car_storage.append([dealership, car])
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and explanation :)